# To run a command in jquery only once after adding content with .append

Tags: jquery, popup, append

How do you run a command in jquery only once?
This is the code that I use:

```
   <script>
    $(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('clicks.open').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#box').fadeIn();
      if('clicks.open'){ $('#boxcontent').append('<p>hello</p>'); }
    });
      $('clicks.close').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('#box').fadeOut();
      });
    });
    </script>
```

There's a link on my page and when you click it, the #box and its #boxcontent opens with the word 'hello'. When you close it, the content seems to be still there because when you click on that link again, it will show up and reload after about three seconds. My question is how to leave the content the way it is as long as the website doesn't get refreshed. I've already searched for answers, but it all looked so difficult and the codes were different as well.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct tells me that `.append()` is causing you trouble. Each click of the button will add an additional `<p>hello</p>` to your box. Maybe try setting the box content using [`.html( htmlString )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Also, you should add the HTML before you fade the box in:

```
$('#boxcontent').html('<p>hello</p>');
$('#box').fadeIn();
```